# Disable IP-isolation on UCP TC7200 Router to enable Chromecast?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I just got my Chromecast, and I've run through the setup, but at the end of the process, it informed me that IP isolation is enabled in my router, so my IPad, IPhone cannot communicate with Chromecast. I have a UCP TC7200 router provided by my cable company (Kabel BW in Germany), and nowhere in my documentation does it mention IP isolation. My German is awful, and English of the tech-support staff is not good enough to understand my issue.

Can anyone explain how to disable IP-isolation for this router, or recommend some trouble-shooting approaches?